# Eigenvalue of nonlinear elliptic equation.

Tags: partial-differential-equations, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, elliptic-equations

For any $u \in H^2(\mathbb R^n)$, consider operator 
$$
Lu = -\frac{1}{2}\Delta u + u - 3u_0^2u
$$
where $u_0$ is a solution of 
$$
-\frac{1}{2}\Delta u + u - u ^3 =0
$$
how to show  $L$ has only one negative eigenvalue ?

In fact, I know $u_0$ satisfy 
$$
|D^\alpha u _0|\le Ce^{-|x|}, |\alpha|\le 2
$$
But I don't know how to show only one negative eigenvalue $L$ has.